# Get currently selected object as an argument for another field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select box that outputs all car objects in cars-array as a select option

```
<select name="car">
    <option ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-value="car">
         //car.car_name//
    </option>
</select>
```

I want to then output all options available with a checkbox, and "check" the option if it's available for that car

```
<table id="options">
    <tr ng-repeat="option in options">
          <td>
             //option//
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkCarOption(car,option)"></input>
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

How do I make sure that the `car` sent into the `checkCarOption()` is the car that's currently selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `ng-model` on the `select`:

```
<select name="car" ng-model="selectedCar">
```

And then you can do

```
checkCarOption(option)
```

and in the function compare it to `$scope.selectedCar`

In fact, you *should not* be doing `ng-repeat` on `option` elements.  you should be using `ng-options` on the `select` element.  You will run into really weird bugs later on if you don't.

```
<select ng-options="car as car.name for car in cars" ng-model="selectedCar" name="car"></select>
```